# Caching Class on Load Balanced Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, deployment

I have a class which does caching in the service layer business objects of my web app.  When the code runs on a load-balanced server, when a client hits one machine and updates their details, but then close the browser, reopen it and happen to hit the website on one of the other machines on the load-balanced solution, their latest changes are not visible.

This basic class is inherited by my other business objects like the People.  Is there a way I can refresh this cached object on the other servers on the load-balanced environment, so the client always sees the latest?

```
   public abstract class CacheStore<T> where T:IComparable, new()
    {
        private class CacheItem
        {
            public T Item
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public DateTime Expires
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        private List<CacheItem> theCache = new List<CacheItem>();

        public abstract TimeSpan Lifetime
        {
            get;
        }

        public int CountAll
        {
            get
            {
                return theCache.Count();
            }
        }

        public int CountExpired
        {
            get
            {
                return theCache.Count(i => i.Expires < DateTime.Now);
            }
        }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            CacheItem i = (from c in theCache where (c.Item.CompareTo(item) == 0) select c).FirstOrDefault();
            if (i != null)
            {
                if (i.Expires < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    theCache.Remove(i);
                    i = null;
                }
            }

            if (i == null)
            {
                theCache.Add(new CacheItem()
                {
                    Expires = DateTime.Now + Lifetime,
                    Item = item
                });
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Filter(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            return (from c in theCache where c.Expires > DateTime.Now select c.Item).Where(predicate);
        }

        public void MarkAsExpired(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            var markAsExpired = from c in theCache 
                                where this.Filter(predicate).Contains(c.Item) 
                                    select c;
            foreach (CacheItem ci in markAsExpired)
            {
                ci.Expires = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Syncing your cache with a central server and have all the servers obtain their cached information from that one?

Comment: Do you have sticky sessions turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lloyd's answer basically covers it.

It's a little unusual to roll your own cache in a .NET application. Generally you would use the caching built into the framework - see [ASP.NET Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for an overview, and [the System.Web.Caching namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If you were doing that, you could for instance invalidate cached data on database changes using [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

For load-balanced environments, though, you would probably be better with a centralized cache as Lloyd recommended. If you want to stay with a Microsoft solution, [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334305.aspx) would be your go-to option.

Comment: Yeah I was looking at these out-of-process solutions.  As I understand them they would take certain firewall rules being setup.  At this point I am thinking perhaps I can either add another key which includes the 'machine name' or using the SqlCacheDependency.  How can I add SqlCacheDependency to this.  The reason I am not considering AppFabric or memcache is because of the hosting provider.  My client wants a quick solution and is doubtful about throwing more 'tools' at it, as they see this as just treating the symptoms of the problem rather than the problem itself.  I want to  use these libs

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected as you're creating the cache within the local app domain that's scoped to the immediate server. Any objects created there are only relevant to that app domain.

To get around this you need to centralize the caching solution to a common server or using something like Couchbase/Memcached so that all servers can share the same cache.